# Having trouble connecting to an mssql database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a database and insert into it using sqlalchemy. I have already succesfully connected to the database using pyodbc but sqlalchemy is giving me trouble.

I am using sqlalchemy so that I can use the `pd.to_sql` method to insert a dataframe into the database.

I checked if the sql version on my computer and the database matched. I also added the database to the "odbc data source" on my computer.

I also ensured that all the credentials are correct and added the version to the sql driver in the connection url.

```
import sqlalchemy

connect_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    'mssql+pyodbc',
    username='******',
    password='*********',
    host='******.database.windows.net',
    port='1433',
    database='*******',
    query=dict(driver='SQL+Server'))

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(connect_url)

engine.execute("SELECT * FROM ********")
```

Error:

```
"InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your code to work by using `query=dict(driver='SQL Server')` instead of `query=dict(driver='SQL+Server')`.